# ClickOnce WinForms Updates and Authentication

Tags: winforms, clickonce

I have done a lot of research on ClickOnce and used it over the years but need a definitive answer on something. If I have a WinForms application leveraging ClickOnce to get application updates, is it true that there is no other authentication scheme other than Windows Authentication that will work?

So for example, if I have a remote user authenticated to a domain via VPN but their machine is ***not*** joined to the domain, will the updates work? I believe the answer is 'No' because even know they are authenticated via VPN, the context which they are running under is say 'MyHomePC\HomeUser' and *not* 'MyWorkDomain\jsmith'. Really this paragraph is a secondary question and a unique use case.

So in a nutshell, is it true ClickOnce for WinForms updates requires Windows Authentication?

Comment: What deployment method are you using? As ClickOnce happily works over the internet, it doesn't inherently require Windows authentication, but if you're deploying from a shared section of a domain, then your users will need to authenticate to the domain..

Comment: Actually your comment (if it has some documentation) is actually the 'answer' if it is true. Do you have any sort of link or documentation stating 'it doesn't inherently require Windows authentication'? Please post and I will mark it as the answer.

Comment: If you want a link, http://www.devx.com/dotnet/Article/33466 - all ClickOnce needs is a URL and the rights to access that resource.